# Parser XML issue in Java using SAXHandler?

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML as below

```
     <rules>
  <user username= "Alice" priority ="0" >
    <expression>Living Existence Sensor.Alice</expression>
    <objects>
      <object>
        <name>LiveFan</name>
        <action>SetPower</action>
        <value>1.0</value>
      </object>
      <object>
        <name>LiveFan</name>
        <action>SetPower</action>
        <value>1.0</value>
      </object>
      <object>
        <name>LiveFan</name>
        <action>SetPower</action>
        <value>1.0</value>
      </object>
    </objects>
  </user>
   <user username= "John" priority ="1" >
    <expression>Living Existence Sensor.Alice</expression>
    <objects>
      <object>
        <name>LiveFan</name>
        <action>SetPower</action>
        <value>1.0</value>
      </object>
      <object>
        <name>LiveFan</name>
        <action>SetPower</action>
        <value>1.0</value>
      </object>
      <object>
        <name>LiveFan</name>
        <action>SetPower</action>
        <value>1.0</value>
      </object>
    </objects>
  </user>
  <rules>
```

I have two users here, but I can have multiple users.

I can save single one object. but I am unable to do so by using  SAXHandler.

Here, I made on object which will save RULE

```
public class CustomRules {

    String username;
    String name;
    String action;
    String value;
    }


@Override
  //Triggered when the start of tag is found.
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                           String qName, Attributes attributes) 
                           throws SAXException {

    switch(qName){
      //Create a new Employee object when the start tag is found
      case "user":
          rule = new CustomRules();
        break;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, 
                         String qName) throws SAXException {
   switch(qName){
     //Add the employee to list once end tag is found
     case "user":
       empList.add(rule);       
       break;
     //For all other end tags the employee has to be updated.
     case "name":
         rule.name= content;
       break;
     case "action":
         rule.action= content;
         break;
  case "value":
         rule.value= content;
         break;
   }
  }

  @Override
  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) 
          throws SAXException {
    content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
  }
```

Here, I have single username, which keeps many rules,

so how can i parser it.

I tried to make List and one object, but I was not successful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is username supposed to be filled from?

Comment: sorry, I updated the Question, now there is username before priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get a flat list of all rules as a result? If so, you need to trigger adding a new Rule on the "object" tag instead of "user".

If you want to preserve the nesting structure, I'd recommend to add a class "User":

```
class User {
   String username;
   double priority;
   List<CustomRules> customRules = new ArrayList<CustomRules>();
}
```

Add a `user` variable to keep track of the current user, similar to the `rule` variable. Create the instance on the "user" start tag, add it to the list of users when encountering the "user" end tag.

Comment: I want to set all rules for one user, then set all other rules for another user.

Comment: I did that, but still many users have their respective rules is not achieved.

Comment: case "object":
       rule = new CustomRules();
        break;

I did this, before you answer. but yet I am stuck in real question.

Comment: can I use one user and respective LIST or HashMap <user, List> ?????

what do you say sir?

Comment: If you want to preserve the hierarchy, you could use a List<List<CustomRules>>, but I'd recommend to add a User class, see updated answer.

Comment: But i already mentioned that I am unable to save this in List, i again try this, Thanks, If you can guide me regarding saving LIST along with name and priority, I will follow your precious guidance.

Answer (score 0):

here is example of parsing list of User where each user have list of rules.

If you need flat list of rules you should get attribute "username" for each user node and save it in instance variable. Creating CustomRules instance should be moved to case "object" in startElemnet just like in my example.

```
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            class User {
                String username;                    
                List<Rule> list = new ArrayList<Rule>();
            }

            class Rule {
                String name;
                String action;
                String value;
            }

            private User user;
            private Rule rule;
            public List<User> users;

            private String content;

            @Override
            public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
                users = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, org.xml.sax.Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                switch(qName){
                    //Create a new Employee object when the start tag is found
                    case "user":
                        user = new User();
                        user.username = attributes.getValue("username");
                        break;
                    case "object":
                        rule = new Rule();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                                   String qName) throws SAXException {
                switch(qName){
                    //Add the employee to list once end tag is found
                    case "user":
                        users.add(user);
                        break;
                    case "object":
                        user.list.add(rule);
                        break;
                    case "name":
                        rule.name= content;
                        break;
                    case "action":
                        rule.action= content;
                        break;
                    case "value":
                        rule.value= content;
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                    throws SAXException {
                content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
            }
        };
```